# Custom gallery showing duplicate images?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-camera

I am storing my camera images into specific folder in my app as well as in my default folder also , i am also having a functionality that user can upload multiple images to server i am doing this by creating custom gallery that is also fine but when i am opening it , it is showing multiple duplicate images because i am storing the images in two places but i want that one image to be displayed i.e only to show my gallery or my specific folder images at a time.
    What i have done is

```
Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);
startActivityForResult(i, 200);


**My OnActivityResult method**


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String[] all_path = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");

            ArrayList<CustomGallery> dataT = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();

            for (String string : all_path) {
                CustomGallery item = new CustomGallery();
                item.sdcardPath = string;

                dataT.add(item);
                imageList.add(string);
            }

            viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
            adapter.addAll(dataT);

        }

}
```

Comment: you are storing image on specific folder and also in default folder. So what is default folder. And you don't to show duplicates then why getting paths of images from both folder ?

Comment: @kibzorg actually what i am doing is storing a compressed form image in specific folder and original image is by default storing in default folder, can you tell me how to get path of my specific folder or of android default folder??

Comment: You means you have to get actual path of selected images from memory ?!